# How to create membership feature in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, membership

I am trying to implement a simple authorization feature for a tentative web community.

I do not know whether I should use Microsoft built-in Membership/Authorization feature or

create everything from scratch. I wish to know if the built-in feature has any restriction

that might hinder professional enterprise programmers from using it. If so, how should I

begin with writing the code from scratch? If not, is there any tutorial around to build

Membership/Authorization feature in MVC4? I am using MVC4 but have no previous experience

with Membership/Authorization feature in MVC projects. It seems that the feature in MVC4 is

somewhat different from that of MVC3, giving me hard time following up MVC3 tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to know if the built-in feature has any restriction
>   that might hinder professional enterprise programmers from using it.

No, none that I know of, I *think* this ASP.NET Membership Feature is also being used here at StackOverflow. [Related Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109967/how-has-stack-overflow-implemented-an-custom-asp-net-membership-provider)

> If not, is there any tutorial around to build, Membership/Authorization feature in MVC4?

You will have to google that out.

> I am using MVC4 but have no previous experience with Membership/Authorization feature in MVC projects. It seems that the feature in MVC4 is somewhat different from that of MVC3, giving me hard time following up MVC3 tutorials.

Yes implementing and using Membership/Authorization feature is same across MVC3 and MVC4.

**Some Links to introduction to Membership/Authorization feature:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx